# In Nunit parameterized test, Assert which only must pass for one case

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

Is there a way to write an Assert which only has to pass sometimes (when the test method is passed arguments from [TestCase] etc)

I have sql being passed to EF SqlQuery<>, and I want to make sure that all properties are being set to proper values.

A way to test this is to make sure that none of the (string) values are null or empty.

The problem is that most of the string values are optional (description, imageurl, etc), and they could be null or empty.
The way I handled this is by taking those fields which happen to be null sometimes, and moved them into a theory.

By moving them into a theory, a case failing an assert won't fail the test, but if all cases fail the assert, the test will fail.

Is there a way to, in a single parameterized test, say something like

```cs
Assert.Sometimes.That(field, Is.Not.Empty)
```

Here's a shortened version of what I'm using now:

```cs
[TestCase(6237)]
[TestCase(8165)]
public void CanGetBookInfo(int aid)
{
    var book = repository.BookInfo(aid);
    Assert.Multiple(
        () =>
        {
            Assert.That(book.Description, Is.Not.Empty);
            Assert.That(book.Name, Is.Not.Empty);
            Assert.That(book.PhotoUrl, Is.Not.Empty);
        });
}

[TestCase(6237)]
[TestCase(8165)]
[Theory]
public void CanGetBookInfoAuthor(int aid)
{
    var book = repository.BookInfo(aid);

    Assume.That(book.AuthorName, Is.Not.Empty);
    Assert.That(book.AuthorName, Is.Not.Empty);
}
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you want in the Theory. If the Assume passes, the assert passes. If the assume fails, then the assert would fail if it were executed. Note that it's generally useless to have a Theory unless you have a valid (lower-case) theory to prove... i.e. Given some predicate, Then we can assert that some other predicate. It almost sounds like you are trying to test that the fields are either empty or not empty, which is pretty much guaranteed!

Comment: I want to make sure the test passes at least one time. Over here, for example, I can't test AuthorName in CanGetBookInfo because it's empty sometimes

Comment: But you can test that the correct thing happens if it's empty and also if it's non-empty. You need specific expectations for each case.